# strange behavior of as.character with data.frame row

Tags: r

```
library(magrittr)

df <- data.frame(NA,1,2,3,4)

df %>% as.character
```

This strangely gives the following. Why is NA converted to an "NA" character?

```
[1] "NA" "1"  "2"  "3"  "4"
```

Transforming the ROW gives me my expected result.

```
t(df) %>% as.character
[1] NA  "1" "2" "3" "4"
```

Type converting NA Obj of course gives an NA type again.

```
NA %>% as.character
```

Comment: You have a `data.frame` with 4 columns and the `as.character` is applied directly on the data.frame.  Did you meant `df <- data.frame(col1 = c(NA,1,2,3,4)); df %>% pull(col1) %>% as.character
#[1] NA  "1" "2" "3" "4"`.  In your example, transposing, converts to `matrix` and `matrix` is a `vector` with `dim` attributes.  If you are applying to 4 columns, do an `unlist` i.e `df %>% unlist %>% as.character`

Comment: Hey akrun, i mean having 4 variables. But why is NA converted to "NA" when applied on a DF. Doesnt make to much sense?

Comment: It is not advisable to apply `as.character` on a `data.frame` directly.  It is applied on `vector`s.  Try `as.character` with more than one rows